# Adding new keys and value to the older dictionary without changing the keys of older dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary in which it contains **URLs** as key and **Open Ports** of their as value. i.e. `dict200 = {}`

```
dict200 = {}
{'http://REDACTED1.com': [21, 22, 80, 443, 3306], 'http://www.REDACTED2.com': [80, 443]}
```

Now I have another dictionary with different content i.e. `newerdict = {}`

```
newerdict = {}
newerdict = {'Drupal , ': '7', 'Apache , ': '2.4.34'}
```

*Now Please assume that the Apache server is being used in the redacted1, and Drupal is being used on redacted2.*

**Now What I want is, something like this:-**

```
{'http://redacted1.com': [{'apache': '2.4.34' }], 'http://redacted2.com': [{'Drupal': '7'}]}
```

Hope this time I explained better. Looking for any reply.

**EDIT:-**

Somehow I am able to replace the positions of values, but now the problem I am facing is, I can't access the properties of dict within a dict.

Here is the full output,

```
http://redacted1.com : [{'\tApache (web-servers), ': '2.4.34'}]
http://redacted2.com : [{'\tDrupal (cms), ': '7'}]
```

But how could I print

```
Apache = 2.4.34
```

Comment: Share desired output as it not quite clear

Comment: can you write an example of how your old dictionary should look like after doing what you have asked for.

Comment: Okay, I will edit this.

Comment: Please I have desired output I can show you. Because Its quite very big. I am not able to show you. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have done few typos, and you can do the formatting by your own. 
You need a mapping to solve this problem.

This will mostly solve your problem

```
dict200 = {'http://redacted1.com': [21, 22, 80, 443, 3306], 'http://redacted2.com': [80, 443]}
newerdict = {'Drupal': '7', 'Apache': '2.4.34'}

mapping = {'http://redacted1.com': 'Apache', 'http://redacted2.com' : 'Drupal'}

new_output = dict()
for key, value in mapping.items():
   new_output[key] = [{value: newerdict[value]}]
print(new_output)
```

**EDIT:**
Using ordereddict to retain insertion order for python version 3.5. [Though python 3.7+ has it built in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dict200 = OrderedDict({'http://redacted1.com': [21, 22, 80, 443, 3306], 'http://redacted2.com': [80, 443]})
newerdict = OrderedDict({'Drupal': '7', 'Apache': '2.4.34'})

dict200_index_wise = list(dict200.items())
newerdict_index_wise = list(newerdict.items())
new_output = dict()
for i in range(len(dict200)):
   new_output[dict200_index_wise[i][0]] = [{newerdict_index_wise[i][0]:newerdict_index_wise[i][1]}]
print(new_output['http://redacted1.com'][0]['Drupal'])
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering, But how can I get the mapping dictionary? as you got that. I can get dict200, newerdict, but can make the dictionary like  your mapping dictionary. That is the main doubt.

Comment: You need to make the mapping dictionary yourself, or you need to find any pattern for linking `dict200` and `newerdict`. Are the insertion order same? I mean *redacted1.com* is on the first place so it should have *Drupal* . or it is a data which you receive from somewhere else?

Comment: Is it possible to make the mapping dictionary without ourself if *redacted1.com* is on the first place and have *Drupal*? If it is possible, please change the code according to it. because then I will have clear picture/

Comment: Yes then you can use ordereddict from the collections library , I can update the answer accordingly if you need it

Comment: Updated the answer using ordereddict

Comment: Okay Cool enough. But How will you access it? For example, I want to print '7' How can I?

Comment: Hi, I have only a little problem, can you suggest me something? I am editing my question on the EDIT portion please see. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Would you like to see my another question regarding Unhassble type list even after passing it on tuple. Here is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610656/unhassable-type-list-even-after-passing-tuple

Comment: Kindly create a question. You edited the question into a completely different question, which is not recommended

Comment: Oh yes I know, But I don't have any option (when I go to ask, I got You have no permission to ask,)

Comment: Hi, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082123/this-code-of-python-is-working-very-slow this is my new question on selenium based. If you would like to help then, please. And this time you will get full info. Thank you.